# Global sections of canonical sheaf and genus

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be algebraically closed and C a curve. Then $g(C) = h^0(C, \omega_C)$. I want to show that if all the degree $0$ line bundles are trivial, then $g = 0$. I can sort of see that if I think of $C$ as a compact complex surface, then being able to shrink down every degree $1$ loop on the surface to a point implies that the surface has no holes. But I am unsure how to obtain a proper geometric argument. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C$ be a complete smooth curve $C$ of genus $g$ over an algebraically closed field.

**An explicit  approach**
Fix a point $p_0\in C$.   Then, if $g\gt 0$, the line bundles $\mathcal O(1.p-1.p_0) \: (p\in C)$ associated to the divisors of degree zero $1.p-1.p_0\in \operatorname {Div}_0(C)$ are pairwise non isomorphic.

**A conceptual approach**
The curve  $C$ has a Jacobian, which is an abelian variety of dimension $g$ and whose closed points parametrize the isomorphism classes of line bundles of degree zero on $C$ .
So indeed it is only for $g=0$ that all line bundles on $C$ are trivial.

Comment: Dear Georges, a comment on your nice answer: the notation $p-p_0$ does not seem to be meaningful unless $g=1$.

Comment: Dear @Asal: By $p-p_0$ I mean the divisor $1.p-1.p_0$. Since it is not obvious to you, it means that the notation is less obvious than I thought. I have clarified the notation in an edit.

Comment: Dear Georges: now that you say it, this notation is indeed completely standard. Pardon my brain slip!